# Decreasing row/column count of gridlayout in android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I need a dynamic `gridlayout` that can be toggled between 3 by 3 and 4 by 4. I can `setRowCount` and `setColumnCount` from 3 to 4 but not from 4 to 3. It will display following issue:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rowCount must be
> greater than or equal to the maximum of all grid indices (and spans)
> defined in the LayoutParams of each child.

Is there any work around to achieve this using gridlayout?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realize this question is quite old, but for people who are still encountering this exception today, I'll offer an explanation that may shed some light upon how downsizing a GridLayout works and why I believe it is/was throwing an exception for the OP.

### In Short:

Child views of the `GridLayout` can, after downsizing, occupy cells that are not within the `GridLayout`'s grid, which is causing the IllegalArgumentException mentioned by the OP. To avoid this, remove child views that will occupy cells outside of the `GridLayout`'s grid before actually calling `setRowCount()` or `setColumnCount()`. This can be done via `GridLayout.removeView(aboutToBeIllegalChild);` or by wiping the entire layout using `GridLayout.removeAllViews();`.

### In Long:

All that calling `GridLayout.setRowCount()` does, is specify a new number of rows that the layout should contain. It does not, however, mess with the child views that the `GridLayout` currently contains, nor it's specified `Spec` (what column(s) and row(s) the child view occupies).

What the exception is basically telling us, and the docs confirm, is that a `GridLayout` does not allow any of its child views to occupy cells that are outside of the `GridLayout`s grid. As an example, the layout will not allow a child view to occupy cell `(5, 1)` when the grid is only `4 x 1`.

This leads us to why the original poster was successful at dynamically increasing the `GridLayout`'s dimensions, while being unsuccessful at decreasing it. When enlarging the dimensions, any child views that were already attached to the `GridLayout` with specified cells, would still be placed in legal cells if the grid received extra rows or columns dynamically. When reducing the dimensions of the grid, child views that were placed in cells that would disappear as a consequence of removing rows or columns, would now be considered illegal.

To work around this, you must either remove those (about to be) illegal child views from its parent `GridLayout` beforehand by calling `GridLayout.removeView(aboutToBeIllegalChild);` or simply wipe the entire `GridLayout` by calling `GridLayout.removeAllViews();`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Based on **Teun Kooijman** answer you can just change **Spec** in **GridLayout.LayoutParams** and keep all **Views** inside the **GridLayout**:

```
private void changeColumnCount(int columnCount) {
        if (gridLayout.getColumnCount() != columnCount) {
            final int viewsCount = gridLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < viewsCount; i++) {
                View view = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                //new GridLayout.LayoutParams created with Spec.UNSPECIFIED
                //which are package visible
                view.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
            }
            gridLayout.setColumnCount(columnCount);
        }
    }
```

You can also change **Spec** in other way by accessing **GridLayout.LayoutParams.rowSpec** and **GridLayout.LayoutParams.columnSpec**

Comment: UpVote: The key point here is to replace the child's  LayoutParams but I had to copy the width and height values from the old LPs to the new LPs.

Comment: Hi, great, I have modified your answer to show how to copy the previous parameters to new one. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514673/decreasing-row-column-count-of-gridlayout-in-android/72693758#72693758

Comment: Not a perfect answer, but still upvoted, because your solution work, need just some small modification to make it perfect.

Comment: @nasser would've been better if you said what is the problem

Comment: I created a menu using that, and after some time on clicking and returning to the menu, the menu glitch like crazy...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was to change the number of columns of the GridView when the app changes the orientation. I achieved it by putting the bellow code in `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`.

```
if (mGridLayout.getColumnCount() != getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nav_columns)) {
        final int viewsCount = mGridLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < viewsCount; i++) {
            View view = mGridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            int colIndex = i%getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nav_columns);
            int rowIndex = i/getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nav_columns);
            layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.width = 0;
            layoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex,1,GridLayout.FILL,1f);
            layoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        mGridLayout.setColumnCount(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nav_columns));
    }
```

The layout parameter values may need change depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Hensin 's answer, I have modify his codes for show how to copy the previous grid items layout parameters as following:

```java
if (gridLayout.getColumnCount() != columnCount) {
    final int viewsCount = gridLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < viewsCount; i++) {
        View view = gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

        GridLayout.LayoutParams oldParams = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        GridLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        newParams.width = oldParams.width;
        newParams.height = oldParams.height;
        newParams.setMargins(oldParams.leftMargin, oldParams.topMargin, oldParams.rightMargin, oldParams.bottomMargin);
                    
        view.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    }
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(columnCount);
}
```

You can now re order your items with almost the same layout parameters